# How can I connect to server using SSL(secure socket layer) on .NET Compact Framework

Tags: .net, compact-framework, sockets

I want to change .NET framework v3.5 to .NET compact framework v3.5.
But I can't change SSL Stream class to compact framework version.
For resolving this problem, I already read some article and msdn library.

http://blogs.msdn.com/cgarcia/archive/2009/08/21/enable-ssl-for-managed-socket-on-windows-mobile.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/cgarcia/archive/2009/08/22/getting-a-managed-socket-to-talk-ssl.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa916117.aspx

but I got an error that is "Unkown error 0x0ffffff", when invoking 'socket.connect(endPoint)' method based on thease article.
In order to find the proper method, I try to use TcpClient class. but i can't solve this problem.

When I try to connect to server on .NET compact framework, TcpClient class didn't work(Smart Device project and windows ce).
As you can see below, I've got the error. In other hand, this code is work on .NET framework(C# console project).

I can't understand why this socket can not access to server.

[image]

[image]

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: If you're testing using the device emulator, have you enabled the network pass through?; In either case, is your test device (real or emulated) able to access the Internet whilst debugging (e.g. open www.google.co.kr in the built in web browser)

Comment: Oh my gosh... thanks for your response. I didn't know about emulator's network setting. It's first time for me to develop program on .NET Compact Framework. After installing ActveSync v4.5, I've solved this problem. The socket was open. Now, I'm going to solve ssl connection. Thanks again Rowland.

Comment: I've solved SSL Connection on .NET Compact Framework. If you want to implement this technique, please refer to link page in my question. And set device or emulator settings. Thanks.